# Odd reputation behaviour

Tags: support, reputation

This is a little odd. I received *seven* points for receiving an upvote to my answer. Any reason? I don't think I've hit the daily rep cap, but if I did, would that be causing an incomplete reputation transfer?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could go to [stackoverflow.com/reputation](http://www.stackoverflow.com/reputation) and see whether you reached the daily rep.

(If reputation on this page does not reflect the reputation shown in your usual use of SO, questions have been deleted or moved. This page is accurate, while the normal reputation shown needs recalculation from time to time. You may request that from a moderator by flagging one of your questions for mod attention or emailing the team if needed and wanted. Recalculations are done automatically sporadically.)

Comment: Wow... is this a 'hidden' feature? I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 2):

> if I did, would that be causing an incomplete reputation transfer

Yes

Comment: So... this can be proven by getting another upvote after this, and not getting any more rep? I'll observe and comment back here.

Comment: @Delan Azabani: Yes, exactly. You can still get rep today from accepts/bounties, but not from upvotes.

Comment: Hmm, exactly. I've gotten a couple more upvotes since then, and they've added no rep.